# Objective-C, NSLocalizedString Random Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I am getting a strange crash due to NSLocalizedString. -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3c6ad0.

I am sure it's due to the NSLocalizedString as when I replace it with static string. everything goes fine. Here is the line where I got the error.

```
[_backButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(sBackButtonDefaultTitle, nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The sBackButtonDefaultTitle is "Back".

What makes it random is that it crashes sometimes and sometimes not.

**EDIT:**

The sBackButtonDefaultTitle is defined in a header file

```
#define sBackButtonDefaultTitle @"Back"
```

The header is, of course, imported into the .m file.

**EDIT:**

More details...this back button title is used application-wide. In almost every controller. However, the crash only happens AFTER pushing certain controller.

This controller contains a web view. If I tap the Back button, the controller is poped. No crash. But If I push any controller with the same "Back" button, the application crashing, giving the error I illustrated above.

It's really mysterious. I hope someone can help me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Surely because you're `sBackButtonDefaultTitle` has been deallocated when you call `NSLocalizedString`.

I guess it's an auto-released string.

You may want to check with NSZombie enabled, to be sure.

You may need to retain the `sBackButtonDefaultTitle` string, when you create it, and release it after the `NSLocalizedString` call.

Comment: sBackButtonDefaultTitle is defined in a definition file.

Comment: #define sBackButtonDefaultTitle @"Back"

Comment: I doubt NSLocalizedString is involved... What makes you think it is?

Comment: If I replace it with the string itself @"Back", I got no crashes. I even tried logging it using NSLog, I got the crash at the NSLog() line.

Comment: Yes. Found no errors at this part. I am thinking it may have to do with Localizable.strings file.

Answer (score 0):

This crash is due to `sBackButtonDefaultTitle` getting released before that point in your code.  Check to make sure you are retaining it when you take possession of it and that you are releasing it **after** using it in that line of code.

Comment: It's a string defined in a definition not an objected being allocated.

Comment: @ShatouDev Please edit your question to show where and how the string is defined.

Answer (score 0):

A good reason of using NSLocalizedString is to support more than one languages for your app. NSLocalizedString usually goes well with string resource file so that the system can dynamically decide with language it should use to populate your UI. I never tried to use the NSLocalizedString as the way you do, but I can tell you use a string resource file will definitely work. Take a look at [Apple's Guidelines for Internationalization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/InternationalGuidelines.html)
and [string resource file](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already use a strings file. But at some point, it seems that iOS can't find the localized string of sBackButtonDefaultTitle.

Comment: You mean iOS could find other strings from the string file but not sBackButtonDefaultTitle? I never seen that case before. If all the strings couldn't be recognized, then your string file didn't get created properly. So you would need to follow the example Apple provide and generate the file from the command line tool.

Comment: That is what make me crazy! I really don't know why this happens!

Comment: What happened? Can you load other strings from the string file but not the one for back button you want? Did that still happen even after you reboot your computer?

Comment: Yes, every other string is loaded without any crashes. I reboot my Mac over 20 times now :)